# RGB Image Metadata

Tags: qgis, r, geotiff-tiff, metadata, landsat-8

How to extract metadata of landsat-8 multi spectral image.(RGB Formation).
I have processed the image, taken out RGB Bands, cropped it and now want the metadata of the combined stack/brick.
Using get_values function i got the values of each band, but unfortunately, the latitudes & Longitudes were missing.

Moreover, once we have a RGB formation, isn't that a metadata or pixel value too will be merged to create one single value against a particular latitude and longitude.

Comment: What specific metadata would you like? Would `gdalinfo` suit your needs?

Comment: coordinates() or as.data.frame(xy = TRUE) will give you centre coordinate values, but it's unusual to want these directly as they are implicit in the extent() and res()olution. Print the thing out to see a summary.

Comment: I intend to perform the land use classification using unsupervised techniques. Now to perform the above, shouldn't i be using the metadata of the images.